# With MySQL and PHP, get rows from table, input a letter grade for rows, then update table

Tags: php, mysql, input, rows

So far, I have the following code...

```
<?php
// Connection information to database omitted....
<form method='get' action='submit.php'>
$counter=0;
echo "<table>"
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
  echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td><td>" . $row[1] . </td>
      <input name='student" . $counter . "'></td></tr>";
  $counter++;
}
echo "</table>
<button name="submitGrades" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>"
?>
```

row[0] is a student ID number and row[1] is their grade.

I would like to enter letter grades for each row, then hit submit to update the table. But I can't seem to figure out how to retrieve each input field.

I was able to get it working by forcing the user to enter a specific student ID, then the grade. It's not optimal, so I would appreciate any assistance. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you should replace your `$counter` with `$row[0]` in the input field. That way you have the student ID, which is presumably unique, in the name of the input field. There are lots of other issues, but this is a major one.

Comment: What other issues do you see? I tried to leave out as much as possible for clarity, but I realize that might have been problematic.

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to comment in detail on stripped code. But: 1. the input isn't in a table cell, or there's one too many </td>. 2. How do you enter grades? There's no input field that I can see. 3. You mix HTML and PHP incorrectly. Etc, etc. But I guess that's all the consequence of stripping out a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

I done this way,
fill the student ID column in the table as a input,name from id0,id1.... like student0,1..
Now, after submit

```
for($i=0;$i<;$counter;$i++)
{
$g="student".$i;
$sid="id".$i;
$grade=$row[$g];
$id=$row[$sid];
$query="update table set grade=".$grade."where sid=".$id;
mysqli_query($query);
}
```

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_query` in the new code as it is deprecated. Also, you have a possible SQL injection hole in your code in the line where you create your query string. Use PDO and bind parameters instead.

Comment: in the query statement grade and id will be replaced by the corresponding student id and entered grade...... this code come after submit... i.e in submit.php

Comment: Thank you to you both. I will try this out.